# Installed OpenCV not working on PyCharms Python 3.8 project

Tags: python, opencv, pycharm, python-3.8

I know there's a lot of answers related to this question, but I really couldn't find the answer so I'm here.

The problem started when I saw cv2 doesn't import on Python 3.8. So I found there's OpenCV whl file available for Python 3.8, I downloaded the whl file, pip installed into Python 3.8 using command:
python3.8 -m pip install opencv_python-4.1.2.30-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl

I confirmed it works on Terminal I opened Python3.8 and entered command: import cv2
And it imported just fine, but when I try import cv2 on my PyCharm project this message keeps showing:
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xMSz.png)

I looked everywhere and I really can't find answer anymore. If anyone can help me I would be very thankful.

Comment: Opencv package name is not `cv2`. Try install using `pip3 install opencv-python`.

Comment: Your PyCharm seems to use a virtual environment which you might not installed OpenCV for. You can activate the virtual environment that PyCharm uses as `source /Users/Phil/PycharmProjects/InstaScraper/venv/bin/activate` then `pip install OpenCV-python`. Or you can install OpenCV-python from inside PyCharm as well.

Comment: @caki That worked like a charm! It was weird, when I activated the virtual environment then pip installed, it said OpenCV was already installed, but when I got back to PyCharm I saw import cv2 working. Thank you so much!!!